# Replace a string with special characters using sed

Tags: macos, sed

I have the below string

```
sec.val.hos.patn=.*app\.com$|localhost$|127\.0\.0\.1$
```

I want replace `.*app\.com$|localhost$|127\.0\.0\.1$` with * so that final string looks like below

```
sec.val.hos.patn=*
```

I am trying to solve this problem using below sed command on Mac OS

```
sed -i ' ' 's~\.\*app\\\.com\$\|localhost\$\|127\\\.0\\\.0\\\.1\$~\*~g' file.txt
```

but unable to get the desired replacement. Can someone please help me to get this working.

Comment: Why are you matching `apple` when input has `app` ?

Comment: I have corrected it please can you answer now ?

Comment: Now your sed works fine on my OSX

Comment: can u please paste the content of the output file and the command u ran on your mac

Comment: It is same command that you have shown. Remove `-i ''` if you want to see output on terminal

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the pattern is actually more complex than you sample, but seems this should do the trick:

```
sed 's/\(^.*=\).*$/\1*/' <<< "sec.val.hos.patn=.*app\.com$|localhost$|127\.0\.0\.1$"
```

Here we capture everything from the start to `=`, then we replace the whole thing with capture group 1 plus `*`.